# Как с помощью python собрать информацию из двух csv файлов?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-2.7

Задача такова: 
в файле 1.csv есть столбец с уникальными значениями типа "OR-SDR-28HD-OLEC". Каждой ячейке этого столбца соответствует значение ячейки соседнего столбца. Есть файл 2.csv, в котором есть значения из первого столбца файла 1.csv. Нужно для значений в первом столбце в файле 2.csv подтянуть соответствующие им значения из второго столбца.

1.csv выглядит следующим образом:

```
Overwrite=No,,"* Changing the setting to ?Overwrite=Yes? will have the added effect of deactivating all of your items from the website except for those listed on this datafeed. If this is not intended, keep ?Overwrite=No?.",,,,,,,,
Part #,Item #,Currency,MSRP,MAP,Checkout MAP,Selling Price,Inventory,Fulfillment Option,Shipping,Activation Mark
PS2-BEC-5780,9SIAFDG6V86915,USD,,0.00,False,26.98,37,Seller,free,True
```

2.csv должен во втором столбце содержать в себе Item # из 1.csv

```
Overwrite = Yes,,* Changing the setting to ?Overwrite=Yes? will have the added effect of deactivating all of your items from the website except for those listed on this datafeed. If this is not intended, keep ?Overwrite=No?.
Part #,Item #,Currency,MSRP,MAP,Checkout MAP,Selling Price,Inventory,Fulfillment Option,Shipping,Activation Mark
PS2-BEC-5780,,USD,,0.00,False,26.98,37,Seller,free,True
```

Comment: В чем у вас возникли затруднения? [Доку и примеры](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) уже читали?

Comment: @MaxU первое затруднение: недостаточно силён в английском. второе: количество ячеек в вышеуказанных столбцах примеро 11к и в дальнейшем будет расти

Comment: 11K строчек для Pandas - это "ни о чем"... ;-) С английским вам тут врядли помогут. Вы уже что-то попытались сделать сами? Приведите в вопросе код (попытки) и маленькие примеры входных данных и то что вы хотите получить в качестве результата...

Comment: @MaxU добавил примеры. Содержание первого столбца будет меняться и каждому Part # приравнивается свой Item #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие задачи:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.read_csv(filename1, skiprows=1, usecols=['Part #','Item #'])
d2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, skiprows=1).drop('Item #',axis=1)

res = d2.merge(d1, on='Part #', how='left')
```

если вы хотите добавить только **один** столбец из другого CSV файла (DataFrame'а), то эффективнее будет использовать метод `.map()`:

```
d1 = pd.read_csv(filename1, skiprows=1, usecols=['Part #','Item #'])
d2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, skiprows=1)

d2['Item #'] = d2['Part #'].map(d1.set_index('Part #')['Item #'])
```

Пример:

```
In [106]: d2['Item #'] = d2['Part #'].map(d1.set_index('Part #')['Item #'])

In [107]: d2
Out[107]:
         Part #          Item # Currency  MSRP  MAP  Checkout MAP  Selling Price  Inventory Fulfillment Option Shipping  \
0  PS2-BEC-5780  9SIAFDG6V86915      USD   NaN  0.0         False          26.98         37             Seller     free

   Activation Mark
0             True
```

**UPDATE:** pandas.DataFrame - это "табличная" структура в памяти. Чтобы сохранить DataFrame в CSV можно использовать метод [DataFrame.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
d2.to_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: к сожалению при выполнении скрипта столбец "Item #" остаётся пустым.

Comment: @ДмитрийВладимирович, приведите в вопросе по несколько строк (4-8) из каждого CSV файла __в виде текста__, чтобы мы смогли его скопировать...

Comment: добавил строки. Мы же о python2.7 говорим, верно? прошу прощения за неопрятный вид текста, пока осваиваюсь на ресурсе

Comment: @ДмитрийВладимирович, в ваших примерах нет ни одного совпадающего `'Part #'` :( Версия Python в данном случае не играет большой роли -методы Pandas будут работать и для Python 2 и для Python 3 одинаково...

Comment: сымитировал совпадение столбцов, поправил данные в вопросе. скрипт всё ещё не вносит изменений во второй файл

Comment: @ДмитрийВладимирович, у меня вносит - смотрите пример в ответе...

Comment: если выполнять Ваш скрипт в консоли или через print - всё работает, но в файл не записывает второй столбец..

Comment: @ДмитрийВладимирович, а как вы его записываете в файл?

Comment: судя по всему - никак o_0. я считал, что последняя строка Вашего примера выполнит запись в filename2

Comment: прошу прощения, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @ДмитрийВладимирович, ‘d2.to_csv(filename, index=False)’

Answer (score 1):

Уникальные значения можно в качестве индекса [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) использовать, тогда достать нужные значения, можно просто используя `df.loc[]`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

# use unique keys as index
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', index_col=0, names=['key', 'value'], header=None)
print(df)

# read as series
keys = pd.read_csv('2.csv', squeeze=True, names=['key'])
print('\nKeys:', *keys)
print('\n', df.loc[keys])
```

Пример вывода:

```
     value
key       
a        1
b        2
c        3
d        4

Keys: b d b

      value
key       
b        2
d        4
b        2
```

Comment: я так понял что автор хочет объединить данные из двух CSV, а не фильтровать... Хотя стоит наверное дождаться что скажет автор вопроса...

Comment: @MaxU: судя по примеру, автор хочет добавить столбец с найденными значениями. Оставлю ответ для других людей, которые также как и я словесное описание задачи поняли (автор один, гугл большой).

Comment: да, может этот ответ кому-то поможет в будущем...